# How to extract amplitude from byte array in android?

Tags: java, android, audio

I am recording sound from mic using audio recorder. recoChunk byte[] store raw recording as shown below.

```
while (isRecording == true) {
    Log.w("myMsg", "recording..");
    recoChunk = new byte[minBuffSize];
    audioRecord.read(recoChunk, 0, minBuffSize);
    mFosRaw.write(recoChunk);
}
```

now from recoChunk I want to find largest amplitude recorded how can I do that?

Comment: If you can assume there is no erroneous DC bias, convert from bytes to a data type which represents samples - most likely `short` - and find the greatest absolute value.  But DC offset or noise peaks may give a result that isn't as meaningful as you might like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast your byte array to an array of a type that matches the bit-depth of your recorded audio in its size. For example for 16-bit audio, you can use `short`, since it holds a 16-bit signed integer value. For 8-bit you can just use the byte array without casting. Then, simply, the largest "number" in the array (you would probably want to take the absolute value) will be the sample with the highest amplitude value.

Comment: yes. audioRecord = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 44100,
      AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
      AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBuffSize);

Comment: short[] cba = ByteBuffer.wrap(recoChunk).asShortBuffer().array(); is giving unsupported operation error.

Comment: I suspect that would have something to do with the usage of the ByteBuffer class. I suggest you look up the correct way to do it in the documentations. For ByteBuffer, this seems to be a good place to look: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html
Although there would be more ways to go about doing what I describe.